# Alternating factorial terms using Java

Tags: java, loops, series, factorial

I'm trying to write a loop in Java that can output the sum of a series which has this form... 1! -3! + 5! – 7! + ... up to n (user gives n as a positive odd number). For example, if the user inputs 5 for n, then the series should calculate the sum of 1! -3! + 5! (hard part) & display it to the user with a basic print statement (easy part). If the user gives 9, then the sum calculated would come from 1! -3! + 5! - 7! + 9!.

**For ease, just assume the user always puts in a positive odd number at any time. I'm just concerned about trying to make a sum using a loop for now.**

The closest code I've come up with to do this...

```
int counter = 1;
int prod = 1;   
n = console.nextInt(); 
while (counter <= n) 
{                  
    prod = prod * counter;
    counter++; 
}   
System.out.println(prod);
```

This does n!, but I'm finding it hard to get it do as specified. Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Consider creating a function that computes the factorial and use the function?

Comment: @devnull From programming style point of view this would be the correct thing to do. However, this would increase the runtime significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to introduce a variable `int sum = 0;` to  store the value of the alternate series.

To only sum every second value, you should skip every second value. You can check that using the modulo operation, e.g. `if( counter % 2 == 1 )`.

If that is true, you can add/subtract the current value of prod to the sum.

To get the alternating part, you can use a `boolean positive = true;` like this:

```
if( positive ) {
    sum += prod;
} else {
    sum -= prod;
}
positive = !positive;
```

Based on the `boolean`, the prod is either added or subtracted. The value is altered afterwards.

Because factorials become very large very fast, it would be better to use variables of type `long`.

Answer (score 1):

As you calculate the factorials, keep a running total of the series so far.  Whenever `counter % 4 == 1`, add the factorial to the running total.  Whenever `counter % 4 == 3`, subtract the factorial from the running total.

You said "any pointers" - I assume that means you **don't** want me to write the code for you.

**Update**

This is closely based on your original code, so that it would be as easy as possible for you to understand.  I have changed the bare minimum that I needed to change, to get this working.

```
int counter = 1;
long prod = 1;   
long total = 0;

n = console.nextInt(); 

while (counter <= n) 
{                  
    prod = prod * counter;
    if( counter % 4 == 1 ) {
        total += prod;
    } else if (counter % 4 == 3) {
        total -= prod;
    }

    counter++; 
}   

System.out.println(total);
```

First up, notice that I have changed `prod` to a `long`.  That's because factorials get very big very fast.  It would be even better to use a `BigInteger`, but I'm guessing you haven't learnt about these yet.

Now, there are those two conditions in there, for when to add `prod` to the total, and when to subtract `prod` from the total.  These both work by checking the remainder when `counter` is divided by 4 - in other words, checking which factorial we're up to, and doing the right operation accordingly.

Comment: Turns out pointers aren't enough. I started loops yesterday & trying to create sums from loops is still very hard for me.

Comment: OK, give me a few minutes, I'll turn this into code.  Or would you prefer for me to spend some time trying to talk you through this?